# Change SQL using Javascript (with buttons)

Tags: javascript, php, sql

I have a table displaying data from a database, buttons with javascript that update the sql and display the result on the table, till here all good, my problem is I want to put more buttons with different SQL queries, this only check the `value=""` of the button and use it as `$var` on the final SQL

Note that I mark the buttons id as btn_01, btn_02..

```
function load_data(query) {
    $.ajax({
        url:"fetch",
        method:"POST",
        data:{query:query},
        success:function(data) {
            $('#result').html(data);
        }
    });
}

var names = new Array('Italy','Denmark','France','UK');
$(".btn").bind("click",function(e) {
    var btn = this.id.split('_');
    var data=( show_mssg(btn[1]) );
    load_data(data);
});

function show_mssg(id) {
    return names[id];
}
```

here is the "fetch" file, is a php file to conned to db

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("dbhost","dbname","user","pass");

$output = '';
if(isset($_POST["query"])) {
    $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["query"]);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `Developers` WHERE `country` LIKE '%".$search."%' ";
}

$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

if ($result) {
    $output='<table></table>';
}

echo "$output";
```

and the html buttons

```
<span id='btn_0'  class="btn" value='Italy'>Italy</span>

<span id='btn_1'  class="btn" value='Denmark'>Denmark</span>

<span id='btn_2'  class="btn" value='France'>France</span>

<span id='btn_3'  class="btn" value='UK'>UK</span>
```

finally to display the result

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

I tried to make similar function with a different array for different buttons but seems like is not working, also i tried with

```
if(isset($_POST["query"]))
```

to not necessary make another function and later try to bind the click on different buttons and just change the sql.

Comment: can you specify _"seems like is not working"_? Because on a first sight this could be alright

Comment: Yeah what behaviour are you getting? Is the query returning an empty result? Is the ajax call not getting anything sent back?

Comment: small hint: you could also do `var data=this.value;` and get rid of all the `id.split`, `names`,..

Comment: is the php file really only called fatch - with out .php? should be `fetch.php` (also in the ajax call) in a standard setup.

Comment: hey! i mean this is actually working, what i want is to add more buttons but with a different array and query :) about the fetch question im starting to use .htacces, is that bad? old way wasnt working, and it works like this